# Results are off

Tags: c++, math

Is something off with my formula for the variables especially for change_in_pennies or is the problem with my choices of the datatypes for the variables? When I input 270 or 280 I get almost everything correct except for the value of pennies where it's a completely random value or number where it should be zero

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im9H1.png)

```cpp
const double quarter_value {0.25};

const double dime_value {0.1};

const double nickle_value {0.05};

const double penny_value {0.01};

int main() {
    
    int amount{}, change_in_dollars{}, change_in_quarters{},
    change_in_dimes{}, change_in_nickles{};
    
    double total{}, change_in_pennies{};

    cout << "Enter an amount in cents : ";
    cin >> amount;

    cout << "You can provide change for this"
    " change as follows: " << endl;

    total = (static_cast <double> (amount) / 100);
    cout << "total: " << total << endl;

    change_in_dollars = (amount / 100);
    cout << "dollars : " << change_in_dollars << endl;

    change_in_quarters = (total - change_in_dollars) / quarter_value;
    cout << "quarters : " << change_in_quarters << endl;

    change_in_dimes = (total - change_in_dollars - (quarter_value * change_in_quarters)) / dime_value;
    cout << "dimes : " << change_in_dimes << endl;
    
    change_in_nickles = (total - change_in_dollars - (quarter_value * change_in_quarters) - (dime_value * change_in_dimes)) / nickle_value;
    cout << "nickles : " << change_in_nickles << endl;

    change_in_pennies = (total - (change_in_dollars) - (quarter_value * change_in_quarters) - (dime_value * change_in_dimes) - (nickle_value * change_in_nickles)) / penny_value;
    cout << "pennies: " << change_in_pennies << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the code in the question.

Comment: Note flipping back and forth between `double`s and `int`s can lead to data loss through truncation. It's best to pick one and stick to it. In this case working in `int`s representing pennies is highly advantageous.

Comment: Anything to do with monetary calculations should stay *far, far away* from floating point values. Work this out in the lowest unit you'll ever need, like pennies. Convert back if/when you need to present the value as dollars.

Comment: As user4581301 has already pointed out you should take the tour. When you ask a question you should clearly explain what the problem is. Like your own the time of the contributors to StackOverflow is precious and you should not expect them to run your code in order to understand what the problem is.

Comment: You have adopted an extremely bizarre habit of declaring variables like `int amount{}` when the convention is `int amount = 0`. In C++11 you can do `int amount { 0 }` but that's more verbose and doesn't really help much.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste the text *as text* into the question. Also please tell us *how* it is "off". Finally please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @JerryTheGreek thanks for the advice but I thought I added a picture but I see your point. user4581301 Thanks for your response and I did get a feeling that if I kept going back and forth, it could lead to some error. Thanks to everyone for the help

Comment: Kind of bizarre that all but one of your `change_in_` variables is `int`.

Comment: @JaMiT the reason why I did that so I can get the values as integers instead of floating point values so I can just do a simple subtraction then divide it by whatever value I'm looking for but it created other problems. I'll try to find a better way to solve it and the pennies variable is a double because it kept giving me a 0 everytime

Comment: @an0nymOusan0nymOus So you had a problem where pennies was 0 every time, and you tried a fix that *did not solve the problem*. Instead of asking for help with your original problem, you asked for help with your flawed solution. Have you heard of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: @JaMiT next time I'll make sure to not make this mistake again, thanks for the advice. I'm just glad that I making these kind of mistakes so I can learn from it. It's all about the learning process

Answer (score 1):

Like others have commented, the problem is likely that your double-to-int conversions are truncated rather than rounded, making even a tiny round-off error lead to a different result. To avoid this, use purely int arithmetic and work in units of cents. Or if you use doubles, make sure to apply `std::round()` before casting back to ints.